# Wordpress Anti Virus exclusions list

Tags: linux, wordpress, anti-virus, best-practices

**Problem background:**

- I am contractually bound to install a system Anti Virus solution on every host.
- For this product I am running Linux (Red hat derived).
- These instances are hosting Apache/PHP with Wordpress sites sitting on them (the database is a separate instance).
- I have performance issues where the AV is scanning the Wordpress site's files on demand, but due to demand for the website this is a lot of repetitive scanning which causes massive CPU spikes and occasionally hangs the system.

**Question:**

I want to know if there is a standard AV exclusions list for Wordpress (or a best practice). I have tried to search online but can't find anything useful (A Wordpress AV plugin is not a system AV so will not pass with my contractual auditors)

Are there an other alternatives than giving the machine more CPU capacity and reducing IO latency?

** Edit **

We are bound by the contract to use one of the big vendors; for security reasons I am not allowed to name which one. 
It does on access based scanning and has a kernel plugin that enables this.
Messages log gets written to on every file scanned. This is a significant number of files due to the sites usage. (60K hits a week on one site that causes the most trouble)

Comment: Where is the slowdown coming from? File locks? Check with files are being locked while the AV runs. I would start with excluding the mariadb/mysql/... Data files. Locks on those tend to cause performance issues on my servers with AV as well.

Comment: Before giving it more CPU, I'd give it more memory. The would allow more files to be cached in RAM, which would significantly reduce disk IO.

Comment: which AV that you ran clamAV?

Comment: I have already added more RAM to the system but this didn't help much. The cache doesn't seem to be used by the AV. I have edited question regarding which AV.

Answer (score 1):

Your ultimate question is about an exclusion list, though your key problem seems to be CPU spikes. As an answer to *that* problem, did you instruct the kernel which processes you want to prioritise? With 'nice' you can give preference to the webserver, keep the AV CPU utilisation within reason.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage

Good software that writes many log entries should have a buffer function (like Nginx has) so it doesn't do disk writes on every line, but only after it has N number of lines to write. Check your AV software to see whether it can do log write buffering.

Comment: I'll check to see if the AV package can do log write buffering, thats a great idea. I reference spikes but it is actually an accumulation as far as I can tell. CPU utilisation rises over time until it consumes 100% CPU and the system becomes unresponsive. The logs show the same files being re checked repeatedly.